# O app fecha quando o usuário sai da conta

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database, realtime-database

Quando o usuário sai da conta o aplicativo fecha.

O problema surgiu quando eu mudei as regras do realtime disso

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

para isso

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    }
}
```

BUTÃO QUE FAZ O LOG OUT

```
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finishAffinity();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

tente assim:

```
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(this).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    // agora o usuário está deslogado
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finishAffinity();
                }
            });
        }
```